# Server-side data table pagination issue and how to load the fast records on view?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeigniter and server-side data table. I am getting the issue on pagination. I have 20k records and I am displaying 10 records per page.

But the issue is, Pagination is displaying but also I am getting all 20k records on-page.

Check this screenshot of the pagination

[image]

The second issue is, I have more then 10lack records in the database. It's displaying on my view but it's taking a lot of time to display. Is there any way to display fast records?

**Controller**

```
public function displayrecords(){
  $order_list=$this->System_model->uploadedList();

 // Datatables Variables
    $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
    $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
    $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));
    $data['draw'] = 1;
    $data['recordsTotal'] = count($order_list);
    $data['recordsFiltered'] = count($order_list);
    $data['data'] = [];
    foreach ($order_list as $key => $row) 
    {
        $arr_result = array(
                    "id" =>"<input name='select_all[]' type='checkbox' class='lead_ids customCheckbox' id='".$row->u_id."'>",
                    "companyname" => $row->u_companyname,
                    "customername" => $row->u_firstname.' '.$row->u_lastname,
                    "mobileno" => $row->u_mobileno,
                    "action" => "<a href=''>click</a>"
        );

        $data['data'][] = $arr_result;

      }
      //print_r($arr_result);
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
    }
```

**Model**

```
public function uploadedList(){

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_Upload');
    $this->db->where('is_active', 0);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#uploadedLead-list').DataTable( {
        language: {
        sLengthMenu: "Show _MENU_",// remove entries text
        searchPlaceholder: "Search",
        emptyTable:     "No record found",
        search:""
      },
        "ordering": false,// remove sorting effect from header 
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "scrollX": true,
        "bInfo" : false,
        "pageLength": 10,
        "ajax": {
            "url" : baseUrl + "/System_control/displayrecords",
            "type" : "POST"
             // "dataSrc": ""
        },
       "columns": [
                { "data": "id","className": "reg_bg" },
                { "data": "companyname" },
                { "data": "customername" },
                { "data": "mobileno" },
                { "data": "action" }
            ]

    });
```

Would you help me out with this issue?

Comment: Your `uploadedList` method should take `pageNo` and `length` variables to fetch the correct set of records

Comment: @CerlinBoss, The length is already in the method. Can you help me with pageNo?

Comment: Length is mentioned but not passed to `uploadedList` method for querying. Page number can be found by pageLength/totalRecords. I think you should read up about pagination before implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your method should look something like below

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function displayrecords() {

    // Datatables Variables
    $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
    $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
    $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));

    // Get total records
    $total_records = $this->System_model->getTotalCount();

    // These params should be used with limit query [LIMIT 0, 10 for first page, LIMIT 10, 10 for second page and so on]
    $order_list = $this->System_model->uploadedList($start, $length);

    $data['draw'] = $draw;
    $data['recordsTotal'] = $total_records;
    $data['recordsFiltered'] = $total_records;

    // Prepare data to output
    $data['data'] = [];
    foreach ($order_list as $key => $row) {
        $arr_result = array(
                    "id" =>"<input name='select_all[]' type='checkbox' class='lead_ids customCheckbox' id='".$row->u_id."'>",
                    "companyname" => $row->u_companyname,
                    "customername" => $row->u_firstname.' '.$row->u_lastname,
                    "mobileno" => $row->u_mobileno,
                    "action" => "<a href=''>click</a>"
        );

        $data['data'][] = $arr_result;

    }

    // echo encoded json
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**MODEL**

```
public function uploadedList($length, $start) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_Upload');
    $this->db->where('is_active', 0);
    $this->db->limit($length, $start);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}

public function getTotalCount() {
    return $this->db->count_all('tbl_Upload');
}
```

Comment: Give me sometime to check your answer

Comment: Can you explain me this?     $total_records = $this->System_model->getTotalCount();

Comment: That method should return total count of `uploadedList` records. Can you add the code from `System_model` file to the question?

Comment: I checked,    echo $start = intval($this->input->get("start")); echo $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));        I am getting both value 0. and Passed this variable to the model and there also I am getting the 0.

Comment: What is the issue with this code?$data['recordsTotal'] = count($order_list);?  I think your answer and my answer are same.

Comment: You are querying the entire dataset to get the count, which is wrong. Get the total count from server and query only the needed records.

Comment: Not sure y start and length is givjng you 0.. check the request sent from datatable in network tab of the browser

Comment: What Output I will get in the $start and $length?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196362/discussion-between-cerlin-boss-and-questionbank).

Comment: I am getting 0 output.